# Node CSV Parser that streams asynchronously, reads line by line and has the ability to pause and resume stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, csv, fs

I am attempting to find a CSV Parser library or a combination of a stream transformation library and CSV Parser that would allow me to take lines upon request (pausing and resuming). Ive found some examples of line by line read streams however those generally deal with plain text instead of CSV format, so I am having trouble determining the right course of action with those examples beyond writing a CSV Parser myself.

The need for this comes in the form of a pseudo-buffer I am creating where I need to send data and receive callback data in a sort of rolling regard. In example if I pull 100 line by line records of csv data and send via HTTP request, I want to be able to pause the stream of records coming in until one of the 100 returns callback data and then I want to unpause the stream, and pull only one record to replace the record that received a callback.

Its a bit convoluted so if I need to better explain please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`csv`](http://csv.adaltas.com/csv/) module can do this. Their [examples page](http://csv.adaltas.com/csv/examples/) has this simple asynchronous example with streams that you may be able to use as a starting point:

```
var csv = require('csv');

var generator = csv.generate({seed: 1, columns: 2, length: 20});
var parser = csv.parse();
var transformer = csv.transform(function(data){
  return data.map(function(value){return value.toUpperCase()});
});
var stringifier = csv.stringify();

generator.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = generator.read()){
    parser.write(data);
  }
});

parser.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = parser.read()){
    transformer.write(data);
  }
});

transformer.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = transformer.read()){
    stringifier.write(data);
  }
});

stringifier.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = stringifier.read()){
    process.stdout.write(data);
  }
});
```